# Como criar uma condição para cada subset dataframe no pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, condição

Eu escrevi o seguinte com o intuito de criar uma condição para um subset de um dataframe em que caso o valor da célula é superior à média desse mesmo subset(neste caso o subset inicial é serem países pequenos e o que eu estou à procura é o valor de uma variável(column no codigo escrito abaixo) desses países pequenos é superior à media dessa variável nesses mesmos paises pequenos).
O Dataframe inicial tem países de todas as dimensões mas quando corro o programa nada acontece.

```
def doule(df, column):
    values = df[column]
    mean = values.mean()
    def higher3(values):
       if values > mean:
          return 1
       if values < mean:
          return 0
       if pd.isna(values) == True:
          return None
    
     triple_bam[(triple_bam.Population_size == 'tiny')][column+'_binary_size'] = values.apply(higher3)
    
doule(triple_bam[(triple_bam.Population_size == 'tiny')],'hc')
```

Aparece
`c:\...\ SettingWithCopyWarning:  A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame. Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Veja o exemplo abaixo, espero que te ajude a resolver

```
>>> import pandas as pd

>>> df = pd.DataFrame({"A": [1,1,2,2], "B": [2,2,3,3]})

>>> df[(df.A == 2)]
   A  B
2  2  3
3  2  3

>>> df[(df.A == 2)]["B"] = 4
<stdin>:1: SettingWithCopyWarning:
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.
Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead
```

`Mesmo erro!` Isso acontece porque vc está tentando associar um valor a um subset do dataframe.

A solução é usar o método `.loc` como sugerido na mensagem de erro. Veja abaixo:

```
>>> df.loc[df.A == 2, "B"] = 4

>>> df
   A  B
0  1  2
1  1  2
2  2  4
3  2  4
```

Ou seja: `df.loc[CONDIÇÃO, COLUNA] = VALOR`

Espero que ajude.